# CALayer disappears when storing in a property

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, calayer

I have a custom `UIPresentationController` in which I overrode the `presentedView` as follows:

```swift
override var presentedView: UIView? {
        guard let view = super.presentedView else { return nil }
        
        let shadowLayer = CALayer()
        shadowLayer.shadowPath = .init(rect: view.bounds, transform: .none)
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 6
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = .init(gray: 0, alpha: 0.15)
        shadowLayer.backgroundColor = view.layer.backgroundColor
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 0, height: -10)
        shadowLayer.shouldRasterize = true
        shadowLayer.rasterizationScale = UIApplication.screen?.scale ?? 1.0
        
        view.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
        shadowLayer.position = view.layer.position
        shadowLayer.bounds = view.bounds
        view.layer.masksToBounds = false
        
        return view
    }
```

Then for efficiency I thought why creating a new `CALayer` every time `presetedView` is calculated and decided to hold the the layer as a property of the class and only update the `shadowPath`. After that the layer is no longer visible and not in the view hierarchy anymore. I also tried to insert sublayer only once by checking if layer is present in the sublayers but it didn't help

Does anyone know what am I missing?

**UPDATE**:
Declared a property

```swift
private let shadowLayer = {
        let shadowLayer = CALayer()
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 6
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 0, height: -10)
        shadowLayer.shouldRasterize = true
        shadowLayer.rasterizationScale = UIApplication.screen?.scale ?? 1.0
        shadowLayer.masksToBounds = false
        return shadowLayer
    }()
```

And deleted initialization code from here. After that the layer dissappears

```swift
    override var presentedView: UIView? {
        guard let view = super.presentedView else { return nil }
        

        shadowLayer.shadowPath = .init(rect: view.bounds, transform: .none)

        shadowLayer.shadowColor = .init(gray: 0, alpha: 0.15)
        shadowLayer.backgroundColor = view.layer.backgroundColor

        
        view.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, at: 0)
        shadowLayer.position = view.layer.position
        shadowLayer.bounds = view.bounds
        view.layer.masksToBounds = false
        
        return view
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you made a mistake when implementing your changes. We can't be sure why your new code isn't working without seeing it. Can you edit your question to add a section at the end where you show your new code and tell us more details about how it goes wrong.

Comment: Every call to `presentedView` is reusing the same layer instance. A layer can only have one `superlayer` at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was calculating layers `position` & `shadowPath` wrong! Because sublayers coordinating system is relative to superlayers system we should draw path inside views `bounds` not `frame` and calculate center point of the frame manually

```swift
    override var presentedView: UIView? {
        guard let view = super.presentedView else { return nil }
        
        
        shadowLayer.shadowPath = .init(rect: view.bounds, transform: .none)
        shadowLayer.position = .init(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
        shadowLayer.bounds = view.bounds
        shadowLayer.backgroundColor = view.layer.backgroundColor

        
        if shadowLayer.superlayer == nil {
            view.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, below: nil)
        }
        
        view.layer.masksToBounds = false
        
        return view
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add code to define your `shadowLayer` as an instance variable and initialize it at the same time:

```
var shadowLayer = CALayer()
```

(You could also make it a lazy property.)

Make that change to your code above, and then just reference the existing`shadowLayer` in your code rather than defining it (and initializing it) in your function.

Comment: That's is exactly the problem, after defining `shadowLayer` as an instance property  it is no longer visible. Really strange

Comment: So post your full code. We can't debug changes you don't share.